# How to use the 'sorted' function for a list of voting results with integer results

Tags: python

I am struggling to print the party names and vote results using the 'sorted' function to achieve alphabetical order. Looking at the image below, you can find an example of the input and how the output should appear:
[Example of expected input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tUmH.png)

```
parties = {}

print("Independent Electoral Commission")
print("--------------------------------")
string1 = input("Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):\n")

while True:
    string1 = input()
    if string1 == 'DONE':
        break
    if string1 not in parties:
        parties[string1] = 1
    else:
        parties[string1] = parties[string1] + 1
print("")
print("Vote counts:")
for key in parties:
    value = (parties[key])
    
    print("{: <10}".format(key),"-", value)
```

For the same input, my program produces:
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OfeP.png)

Answer (score 2):

use `sorted` function

```py
parties = {}

print("Independent Electoral Commission")
print("--------------------------------")
print("Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):\n") # Print Instead INPUT otherwise FIRST input will be skipped

while True:
    string1 = input()
    if string1=="DONE":
        break
    if string1 not in parties:
        parties[string1] = 1
        
    else:
        parties[string1] += 1
        

print("")
print("Vote counts:")
for key in sorted(parties):
    value = (parties[key])
    
    print("{: <10}".format(key),"-", value) e)
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot - didn't realize it was that easy! One last question I now have and has come up is that it appears my program does not count the first word entered as a vote, either that or it has something to do with the lettering. For example, in my input 'apples' is entered twice, but only counted once? Hope this makes sense?

Comment: @JoshPenne Check my Updated ANSWER.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you using the input function for just printing a line (It accepts one input but it is not counted as the while loop overwrites the variable 'string1' by taking input again).Instead you should do :

```
print("Enter the names of parties (terminated by DONE):\n")
```

And yes you can sort a dictionary keys by using `sorted()` as mentioned in the answer by
[Giorgi Imerlishvilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8929688/giorgi-imerlishvili)